# tempdb not releasing free space after reboot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

I know there are many posts on the 'net about shrinking the tempdb, but usually it's about 'without restarting and restarting fixes it'.

Usually our tempdb data file sits around 8M.  On friday I was doing a check of space on server and found it at 8G.  The tempdb log file is fine.

Saturday night the server gets rebooted so I thought I would wait and simply check that that would release the 99% of free space it was showing.

It didn't.
I did the following today, when there was no one on network.

- I've tried restarting the service, which worked in the past
- I've tried shrinking database and files (all showing 99% free)
- I've done a transaction log full backup of the two 'main' databases in the instance
- tried DBCC FREEPROCCACHE, DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE (‘ALL’), FREESYSTEMCACHE (‘ALL’), FREESESSIONCACHE, DROPCLEANBUFFERS, DBCC SHRINKFILE (N’tempdev’, NOTRUNCATE), DBCC SHRINKFILE (N’tempdev’ , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)

  SELECT SUM(size)*1.0/128 AS [Tempdb size in MB] FROM tempdb.sys.database_files

gives 8108.625

```
 SELECT
 SUM (user_object_reserved_page_count)*8 as usr_obj_kb,
 SUM (internal_object_reserved_page_count)*8 as internal_obj_kb,
 SUM (version_store_reserved_page_count)*8  as version_store_kb,
 SUM (unallocated_extent_page_count)*8 as freespace_kb,
 SUM (mixed_extent_page_count)*8 as mixedextent_kb
FROM sys.dm_db_file_space_usage
```

gives

usr_obj_kb  internal_obj_kb version_store_kb    freespace_kb    mixedextent_kb
1088    102848  512 7985216 14272

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'tempdb' )
```

gives messages
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE: File ID 1 of database ID 2 was skipped because the file does not have enough free space to reclaim.
Cannot shrink log file 2 (templog) because the logical log file located at the end of the file is in

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm another of those trying-to-self-teach computer people doing double-duty as dba admin in a medium-size company.

Comment: Can you check and share if you have any open transactions on that server?

Comment: DBCC OPENTRAN returns No active open transactions.

Comment: Two thoughts: your shrinkdatabase did not give a target size, did you try setting one? Second, is it possible the initial size was modified and set to 8G? UI way to find it: right click on tempdb, properties, go to Files, look at initial size. I assume you have only one tempdb data file, from your description. Also, review dbcc shrinkfile for good information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15